# Dummy-coded moderator (multi-level): Reversing code changes interaction results

Tags: categorical-data, interaction, multilevel-analysis

I have a diary-study (multi-level data) and hypothesized an interaction effect on level 1 (day-level). The moderator is a dummy-coded variable that was measured at day-level (*eat vs. not eat), the IV is a continuous variable that was also measured at day-level. I used HLM for the analyses and R (calculator) to test the simple slopes.

My hypothesis was that "eating" would buffer the negative effect of the IV on the DV. I do find this effect in my data, but the interaction effect is only significant if I code my dummy moderator like this: [1=not eat; 0=eat].

I can understand why this may happen technically (the interaction term is built by multiplying the centered IV with the moderator and it makes a difference, which moderator values are 0 because "0 times something" is always 0). However, **I am not sure how I can write about this.**

**(1)** First, it seems a little unusual to me to code 1=not eat and 0=eat. Do I have to give arguments for this in my paper?

**(2)** Second, my hypothesis was that "eating" will buffer the negative effect of my IV on the DV. My data now "tells me" that not eating on days with high levels of my IV is bad. **(2a)** Is it correct to treat my hypothesis as "confirmed" and state that eating can indeed be a resource on days with high levels of the IV? **(2b)** Is the "absence of an otherwise negative effect" enough to call something a resource? (Maybe this question is not the right one here but I would be very interested to read your opinion!). **(2c)** A person I have talked to about this said that I should maybe write that the hypothesis was "partly confirmed" but I do not really understand what that would mean then.

**(3)** Third, the same for "practical implications": Can I state that people should eat on days when the IV is high or do I have to write that they should "not not eat"? The latter would make my paper much more difficult to read... but I am just not sure how I should deal with the fact that the interaction is not significant when I reverse the values of my moderator.

**(4)** Generally: Did anyone ever try to reverse the values of a dummy-coded moderator and see, if the interaction term stayed significant? How would you interpret the results, if this was not the case?

**I would appreciate your help a lot!**

(*Please note that "eating" was chosen as a placeholder for my binary moderator variable in order to make the problem easier to understand)

*This is how the interaction looks like (with 1=Not eat[No]; 0=eat[Yes])*
[image]